# Discord-бот выдает роли на основе имен пользователей

Tags: javascript, discord

Я создаю бота для модерации Discord, одной из составляющих этого бота является следующая задача:

«Когда каждый новый пользователь заходит на сервер, его роль по умолчанию будет @NotMember, но когда он меняет свой серверный никнейм на «Никнейм |  (Настоящее имя)", например, CoolPerson (Алекс), то его роль автоматически меняется на @Member".

Единственный способ сделать это, который я вижу, — проверить, содержит ли имя пользователя скобки, если нет, то его роль — старая @NotMember.

Есть ли другой способ определить, изменили ли участники сервера свое имя на псевдоним?  И возможно ли это на самом деле?

Я делаю этого бота на JavaScript, но здесь также приветствуется Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы проверять изменения никнеймов воспользуемся обработчиком

[**on_member_update(before, after)**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member#discord.on_member_update)

`before` и `after` аргументы имеют тип `discord.Member`, так что мы можем сравнить никнейм пользователя **до** и **после**, обратившись к свойству `nick`.

Если никнейм изменился и при этом не был убран, то можем проверять соответствие никнейма форме

```py
if before.nick != after.nick and after.nick != None:
```

Запишем в отдельную переменную никнейм, резделенный на 2 части по строке `' | '`

```py
    splitted_nick = after.nick.split(' | ')
```

Если количество элементов в списке `splitted_nick` равно `2`, значит никнейм имеет 2 части и можно работать со второй, для проверки скобок. Далее просто проверяем, чтобы вторая часть никнейма начиналась с `'('` и заканчивалась на `')'`

В противном случае забираем роль

```py
    if len(splitted_nick) == 2:
        if splitted_nick[1].startswith('(') and splitted_nick[1].endswith(')'):
            await after.add_roles(role)
        else:
            await after.remove_roles(role)
    else:
        await after.remove_roles(role)
```

---

**Полный код:**

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if before.nick != after.nick and after.nick != None:

        # роль, когда ник не по форме
        not_member_role = after.guild.get_role(id)
        # роль, когда ник оформлен правильно
        member_role = after.guild.get_role(id)

        splitted_nick = after.nick.split(' | ')

        if len(splitted_nick) == 2:
            if splitted_nick[1].startswith('(') and splitted_nick[1].endswith(')'):
                await after.add_roles(member_role)
                await after.remove_roles(not_member_role)
            else:
                await after.remove_roles(member_role)
                await after.add_roles(not_member_role)
        else:
            await after.remove_roles(member_role)
            await after.add_roles(not_member_role)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```